# Illegal State Exception in java

Tags: java, exception, awt, illegalstateexception

I'm getting this exception when I run my code. Even though the code runs fine, I'm getting some exceptions on the terminal

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at SR.start(SR.java:38)
    at SR.mouseClicked(SR.java:212)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2025)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper$5.dispatchEvent(AtkWrapper.java:700)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What am i doing wrong??

My `start()` method

```
private void start() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (HelperThread == null)
        HelperThread = new Thread(this);
    HelperThread.start();
}
```

Comment: So, you tried to start a thread which has already finished?

Comment: Shall i  attach my code?

Comment: I have given my start() method and there is no way i can start a thread which is already finished

Comment: Is there any chance you're starting the same thread twice? (This is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: Wow ! that solved

Comment: Do you mean that @JoeC gave you the answer?

Comment: So, if HelperThread is NOT null, it will try and start the thread again

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be starting the same `Thread` twice, which is not allowed.

If you're looking to reuse the same thread, I would recommend creating an `ExecutorService` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if HelperThread is not null (it already exists) and you call HelperThread.start() is tries to start() a thread that has already started or finished it's processing.  If you want to restart processing, you'll have to stop the thread first.  To do this gracefully, use a while (running) { } pattern in the actual thread.  Then, int the start()-method, set the flag to false, wait for the thread to die and then start a new thread:

```
private void start() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (HelperThread != null) {
        running = false;
        HelperThread.join(); // wait for it to die...
    }

    // Start fresh...
    HelperThread = new Thread(this);
    HelperThread.start();
}
```

Also, as a side note, avoid using capital letters as the first letters for variables.  It should rather be "helperThread".